# VBA and Access 2007 data validation, Login trouble

Tags: forms, vba, authentication, ms-access-2007

Please bear with me I am a complete noob at VBA, I had no intention of writing code but I ended up doing so anyway because I couldn't see how I'd achieve what I was looking for without it. I have been searching on the internet for 3 days 10 hours a day without much luck. I have an Access database that I'd like to secure. Just let me explain what I am trying to achieve first:

1) I have a combobox in a form that looks up values in a table, the item code of an item. This is basically an inventory thing. I have a query that has a calculated field which returns the remaining stock of each item. I have another query which takes the item code as the parameter and returns the remaining stock for that specific item code.

What I want to do is check if the remaining stock is 0, if it is, then on selecting this item code from the combobox list, have a msgbox display a message saying that the item is not in stock and so it cannot be issued, and reset the combobox (i.e. as if no selection was made)

Here's my code; the combobox's afterUpdate event:

```
Private Sub Item_Code_AfterUpdate()

Dim dbMyDatabase As DAO.Database

Dim rsMyRecords As DAO.Recordset

Dim strQuery As String

strQuery = "SELECT [Store_Items].[Item Code], Store_Items.[Opening Stock], IIf((Nz([Opening Stock],0)+Nz([Quantity Purchased],0)-Nz([Quantity Issued],0)<0),0,(Nz([Opening Stock],0)+Nz([Quantity Purchased],0)-Nz([Quantity Issued],0))) AS [Remaining Stock] FROM (Purchases RIGHT JOIN Store_Items ON Purchases.[Item Code] = Store_Items.[Item Code]) LEFT JOIN Issuances ON Store_Items.[Item Code] = Issuances.[Item Code] WHERE (((Store_Items.[Item Code])=[Forms]![Issuances]![Item Code]));"

Set dbMyDatabase = CurrentDb

Set rsMyRecords = dbMyDatabase.OpenRecordset(strQuery)

Dim Msg, Style, Title, Response

Msg = "This Item is out of Stock! You Cannot Issue this item!"
Style = vbOK
Title = "Warning!"

If rsMyRecords![Item Code] <= 0 Then
Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title)
If Response = vbOK Then Me![Item Code].Requery

End Sub
```

2) Ive made 2 versions of a navigation panel. One of them has access to all of the forms, and the other one has limited access. This is to be decided by the login type. Now, the only one that works is the first one, I don't understand why the ElseIfs aren't working. When I try logging in with other types, on clicking the login button, nothing happens.

I also want to hide the navigation pane and access default menus that allow database design editing and viewing of tables and forms in design views depending on the login type but I have no idea how to achieve this.

```
Private Sub LoginBUtton_Click()

'Check to see if data is entered into the UserName combo box

    If IsNull(Me.CBOLogin) Or Me.CBOLogin = "" Then
      MsgBox "You must select a user type.", vbOKOnly, "No User name"
        Me.CBOLogin.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Check to see if data is entered into the password box

    If IsNull(Me.TextPass) Or Me.TextPass = "" Then
      MsgBox "No Password Entered, Enter a password.", vbOKOnly, "No Password"
        Me.TextPass.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Check value of password in Users to see if this
    'matches value chosen in combo box

    If Me.TextPass.Value = DLookup("Password", "Users", _
            "[UserID]=" & Me.CBOLogin.Value) Then



    ElseIf (Me.CBOLogin.Value = "Developer") Then
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "LoginForm", acSaveNo
    DoCmd.OpenForm "FullAccessNav"


    ElseIf (Me.CBOLogin.Value = "Office") Then
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "LoginForm", acSaveNo
    DoCmd.OpenForm "LimitedAccessNav"


    ElseIf (Me.CBOLogin.Value = "Store") Then
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "loginForm", acSaveNo
    DoCmd.OpenForm "LimitedAccessNav"

    Else
            MsgBox "Password Invalid. Please Try Again", vbOKOnly, _
            "Invalid Entry!"
            Me.TextPass.SetFocus

    End If

    'If User Enters incorrect password 3 times database will shutdown

    intLogonAttempts = intLogonAttempts + 1

    If intLogonAttempts > 3 Then
      MsgBox "You do not have access to this database.Please contact admin.", _
               vbCritical, "Restricted Access!"
        Application.Quit
    End If

End Sub
```

Help Please? :S

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed to fix the login issue, but I am still stuck with the data validation bit. I get a runtime error 3421 when I click on an item code from the list in my combo box.

This is what I want to happen when I have selected an item code from the combo box. I want to get the calculated field from a query for that item code, (this calculated field has the calculated remaining stock of an item) if it is 0, then i want to display a msg and prevent the user from entering this record, so i suppose resetting the combobox will do?

If the stock is at a certain level, i just want to display a msgbox and that's all, normally let the user enter the record, otherwise, the user just enters the record in normally.

I am getting a runtime error 3421 "Data type conversion error" at this line:

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Remaining Stock] FROM [InventoryStatusSpecificItem] WHERE [Item Code] = [Forms]![Issuances]![ItemCBO]", Dynaset)

```
Private Sub ItemCBO_AfterUpdate()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb()


    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Remaining Stock] FROM [InventoryStatusSpecificItem] WHERE [Item Code] = [Forms]![Issuances]![ItemCBO]", Dynaset)



    If rs.Fields([Remaining Stock]) = "0" Then
    MsgBox "This item is out of stock! Cannot Issue!", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Attention!", vbExclamation
    Me!ItemCBO = Null

    ElseIf rs.Fields("Stock Status") = "Order Now!" Then
    MsgBox "This item has reached its minimum quantity level. Only " + StrRemainingStock + " remains. Quantity Measured as " + StrMeasuredIn, vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Attention!"

    Else
    Me!ItemCBO.Requery

    End If

    'close recordset
    rs.Close
    Set db = Nothing
```